# Insufficient privileges to complete the operation on adding Guests users to AAD M365 group

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I created two M365 groups in my demo tenant. On running:

> Get-UnifiedGroup group1@M365xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com |fl Allow

I see:

**AllowAddGuests : True for one group (group1)**

and

Get-UnifiedGroup group2@M365xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com |fl Allow

I see:

**AllowAddGuests : False for other group (group2)**

When I (as an owner of both groups) try to add a Guest user ***via Azure Portal***, I see guest user added successfully to group1 and error ***Insufficient privileges to add the selected members*** on trying to add guest user to group2 which are working as expected.

When I (as an owner of both groups) try to add a Guest user ***via MS Graph Explorer***, I see

```
{

    "error": {

        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",

        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",

        "innerError": {

            "date": "2023-05-12T06:46:19",

            "request-id": "973cce1b-fadd-45b7-8b52-ac708cb56e58",

            "client-request-id": "266f9f3e-9935-9468-ef46-eba5296166d9"

        }

    }

}
```

for both groups.

Why is that? I should be able to add guest user to group1 via Graph Explorer. Why is it behaving differently when using Azure Portal v/s MS Graph Explorer? What I missing?

Answer (score 0):

With the following command , I got the existing unified groups:

```
Get-UnifiedGroup | Format-List DisplayName,EmailAddresses,Notes,ManagedBy,AccessType
```

[image]

I have the following permissions which are not granted admin consent for an app while login.

[image]

So when tried to add a guest user to such a group where permissions are not granted by admin during the login, I got the following error:

```
"error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
}
```

[image]

Make sure to give desired permissions to add guest users as members to the unified groups.

**Permissions:**

```
email ,openid ,profile ,Directory.ReadWrite.All ,Group.ReadWrite.All   ,GroupMember.ReadWrite.All UnifiedGroupMember.Read.AsGuest , User.Read ,User.ReadWrite.All
```

scope defined as : `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

[image]

***Logged in to my application with permissions granted:***

**GET** `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxbedf&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms`

Recievd token:
**POST** `https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/token`

***Then with the following query I could add the guest user to my ms365 group .***

**POST**  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupObjId>/members/$ref`

**Headers:**

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:Bearer
```

**Body:**

```
{
    "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/”<Guest User ObjectId>"
}
```

***executed:***

[image]

***guest user added to unified group:***

[image]

**Reference** : [Add a member to a group | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-add-a-member-to-a-group)

Comment: Thank you! The issue is is that if I add the Graph permission, I can add Guest users even if guest user policy setting is set as False which I not correct.

Comment: + I can add non-guest users without these permissions. I see this issue when adding Guest users.

Comment: In the case where it is  not needed for all groups , have you got a chance to  change the policy setting to allow guest users to join that particular group.For this owner role is needed!

Comment: Yes policy setting is set correctly. Owner role is added as well.

Comment: Can you try setting guest policy setting: false and try to add a guest user with the above graph permission. Please let me know if you are able to add or not.